# Using test class to fill ArrayLists with data that will be used by the program

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, bluej

I am a Computer Science student at a university and until a couple days ago, we've been using BlueJ IDE.
Since we haven't been taught how to use databases yet, to store various data in our program , we would create Container classes with ArrayLists (or whatever else) and methods to fill them with data. To "store" that data, we used the methods in JUnit test classes( in @Before setUp() method)  and before running the program , we would right-click the test class in BlueJ interface and select "Test fixture to object bench", that created all the objects needed to fill the ArrayLists and then we launched the program that would be able to see the data in the ArrayLists.

Right now , we have a GUI assignment in Eclipse for the same software as before ( that one had a Text UI) and I'm trying to recreate the same thing from BlueJ in Eclipse. The problem is , I've only manage to RUN a JUnit class, I can't find anything similar to the BlueJ's "Test fixture to object bench".

Basically , I need to somehow run a test class that fills the ArrayLists, but right after it does that , launch the Gui program. I've tried calling the main() method from JUnit( in @Test ) and it would only finish as a normal JUnit test , without showing me the GUI.

Can somebody please help me out ? Feel free to ask any more questions.

Comment: Do you ever call the GUI? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this?

```
private Collection<String> myArray;

@Before
public void startUp() {

       myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
       myArray.add("data");
}
```

Which version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: Well my problem isn't filling those arrays in the JUnit class , my problem is that I need to somehow use JUnit to fill those ArrayLists and then run the GUI (while the arraylists are still filled), which stays open and I can test button actions etc.
I am using JUnit 4.

Comment: I see now... so you are not unit testing, you are using JUnit as bootstrap for your app. So basically your test method will replace your static main method, every time you run the test it would start the GUI window.

@Test
public void testBootstrap {
    MyGui my = new MyGui(myArray);
}

Comment: I've tried that , it seems to create and open the GUI class , but closes it immediately and finishes the unit test without any errors. I need to be able to interact with the GUI, after the JUnit sets up the arraylists .

Comment: Add this to the end of your test method.
while(true) {}
It's not pretty to do that, but I think it will do the trick.